# Flume Twitter data streaming setup issue

Tags: twitter, flume, cloudera-cdh

I'm geting following exception while extracting Twitter data using Flume on CDH4.

> twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Receiving status stream. Exception in
>   thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   twitter4j.json.JSONObjectType.determine(Ltwitter4j/internal/org/json/JSONObject;)Ltwitter4j/json/JSONObjectType;
>     at
>   twitter4j.AbstractStreamImplementation$1.run(AbstractStreamImplementation.java:100)
>     at
>   twitter4j.internal.async.ExecuteThread.run(DispatcherImpl.java:116)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue in my code, but when I changed the .jar from `twitter4j-core-2.2.6.jar` to `twitter4j-stream-3.0.0.jar` it got resolved.

The main reason behind this issue was due to  `FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();` was used in the code and `FilterQuery` class is present in `twitter4j-core-2.2.6.jar` but it has some problem and due to this the issue was coming. If we replace the `twitter4j-core-2.2.6.jar` with `twitter4j-stream-3.0.0.jar` then it also contains `FilterQuery` class and issue gets solved.